# Piping Value: Ajax + JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function in which I execute an ajax request and wait till I get a response and return a value but the value returned is undefined. What is wrong?

```
            function GetVMData(url_s){ 
                return $.ajax({ 
                       url: url_s, 
                       crossDomain: true,  
                       dataType: 'jsonp', 
                       error: function(xhr, status, error) {  
                           alert('failed') 
                        }  
                   }).pipe(function(data) { return data[4]; }); 
            }
```

If I print the value of data[4] within the ajax callback it prints the right value, therefore i know the request is going through but when I try this:

```
            var cord;
            cord = GetVMData(url).done(function(cpu_USG) { 
            return cpu_USG;
            }); 
            alert(cord)
```

the value of cord is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
var cord;

cord = GetVMData(url).done(function(cpu_USG) { 
  return cpu_USG;
});

alert(cord);
```

`cord` contains object, not the value. And by the way, you don't know where ajax calling will be finished, so you should be familiar with idea of callbacks..

As an example:

```
function makeRequest(url, callback) { 
  $.ajax({
    url: url, 
    crossDomain: true,  
    dataType: 'jsonp',

    error: function(xhr, status, error) {  
      alert('failed') 
    },

    success: callback
  }); 
}

var do_something = function (data) {
  alert(data[4]);
};

cord = makeRequest(url, do_something);
```

Comment: you just repeated the code that I have written. How do i get the value then ?

Comment: I have a lot of other sections that use that value, so should I just encapsulate all those section within the callback ?

Comment: @Speransky Danil: callbacks is what he originally had. Deferreds are easier to work with and practically callback solution doesn't change **anything**

Comment: @user1454693: why did you check this answer?! You had nice code with callbacks, now you have weird code with callbacks. Cannot get it o_O Callbacks will be deprecated in further jquery releases, so no reason to use it

Comment: @Speransky Danil: 1. deferreds is what will change callbacks soon (callbacks are deprecated in 1.8) 2. deferreds are **much** more flexible 3. have a look at his previous question 4. if "straigh hands" == "using old and obsolete techniques" - then feel free doing that

Comment: @Speransky Danil: yep, it makes the code much easier to maintain. And as I said - callbacks for `$.ajax` are deprecated. Callbacks are limited with only one function to process the result, with deferreds you can have any amount you want

Answer (score 2):

```
    var cord;
    cord = GetVMData(url).done(function(cpu_USG) { 
    return cpu_USG;
    }); 
    alert(cord)
```

This code runs asynchronously. So you need to perform **everything** in the callback, like:

```
    GetVMData(url).done(function(cpu_USG) { 
        alert(cpu_USG);
    });
```

Comment: the GetVMData function will be called from another function that needs the cpu_USG value how can i achieve that. So from the previous example cord will be used to graph a chart.

Comment: @user1454693: so what? You **have to** use it in the way I've demonstrated. This is how deferred and asynchronous calls work

Comment: so are you saying that I should encapsulate all the code that uses that value inside the callback ? isnt there another way of achieving this ?

Comment: @user1454693: as soon as deferred is resolved (it happens when ajax request finishes successfully) the callback is called. And you get all the data in the callback and in the callback only. PS: deferreds made the dealing with ajax million times easier, so I cannot get what confuses you.